# how to calculate expectation $X$ continuous and $Y$ discrete

Tags: probability, random-variables

if has density $f(x,y) = \dfrac{12}{13}x^y,\quad  0<x<1, \quad y=1,2,3$, how to calculate  this expectation $E(Y\mid X=x)$?

I am confused because $X$ be continuous random and $Y$ be discrete random variables. help please

Comment: Is y equal to 1, 2 or 3, or is it any positive integer?

Comment: @Paul: It must be $\{1,2,3\}$, elsewhere it's not a valid density

Comment: Either way, the distribution is not properly normalized.

Comment: Yes it is. See in my answer the marginal $p(x)$ (which integrated gives 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be, indeed, confusing, to speak of "density functions" of mixed discrete-continuous variables, (actually here we have a [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) in the continuous dimension and a [pmf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) in discrete variable), the rigourous way is to use distribution functions. Anyway, there's not much problem here, you can compute the marginals directly:

$$p_X(x)=\sum_{y=1}^3\frac{12}{13}x^y=\frac{12}{13}(x+x^2+x^3) \qquad (0\le x\le 1)$$

(this is a density - sanity check: $\int_0^1 p_X(x) dx=1$).

And then compute the conditional 
$$p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{p_{X Y}(x,y)}{p_X(x)}=\frac{x^y}{x+x^2+x^3} \qquad (0\le x\le 1 , y\in \{1,2,3\})$$

(this is, for each fixed $x$, a probability mass function - sanity check: $\sum_{y=1}^3 p_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x)=1$)

and from that the expectation:
$$E(Y\mid X=x)=\sum_{y=1}^3 y \frac{x^y}{x+x^2+x^3}=\frac{x+2x^2+3x^3}{x+x^2+x^3}$$

Comment: It is P_{Y/X}(y/X=x), it is not the opposite.  I am wondering?

Comment: @satishramanathan : yes, I misread the question, fixed

Comment: I changed $E(Y|X=x)$ to $E(Y\mid X=x)$.  $\qquad$

Comment: Thank leonbloy, I have a question, what interpretation can be given to $E(Y|X=x)$? in this case

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's the usual interpretation of conditional expection. You should sketch a graph of the mixed discrete.continuos X;Y joint density, and picture $p(Y|X)$ as "cuts" along a fixed $x$

Answer (score 2):

I have given the solution in an image.  Hopefully it is legible.

[image]

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: y has only 3 values, not infinite.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question but the method is the same, instead of infinity, she has to calculate for just three terms, I shall edit it.  Thanks

Comment: @Paul, Does it answer the question.  Hopefully yes!!.

Comment: Thank satish ramanathan, I have a question, what interpretation can be given to E(Y|X=x)E(Y|X=x)? in this case

Comment: We call this the conditional expectation of Y given X to be some value x.  That is the interpretation that I would give.